# how to upload jrxml file in jaspersoft studio? sftp

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

After editing a jaspersoft template in Studio version 6.0.3 is it possible to export or upload the jrxml file to my server via sftp directly from JasperSoft Studio?

Currently after edits are made and saved I have to go to the ftp client to upload files.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use Eclipse RSE installing the dedicated feature. It's possible from Jaspersoft Studio. You simply need to add the update site for it.
I would suggest you use Indigo one, because the Juno (dedicated to 4.2.x) may screw up UI and other JSS capabilities. 
Even if the Eclipse 3.8.2 version, the platform used by JSS product, is referred as Juno, it can be more like a bug-fix version of Indigo 3.7.x.

So you could add the Indigo update site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/
Later you can select the feature "Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime", install it and you are free to try if it suits your needs.
See screenshot below:

[image: RSE plugin installation]

Personally I simply installed, but I didn't play with it.

Anyhow I suggest you to also give a look to the following blog post: http://rays-blog.de/2012/05/05/94/use-winscp-to-upload-files-using-eclipses-autobuild-feature/

Maybe it's better to set-up a custom script, like this user did because not completely satisfied of the Eclipse-like solutions.

It's worth mentioning also this one: http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-sftp/
In my case it didn't work even if installation appeared to have completed successfully. Maybe it's too old for the latest Eclipse versions.

Regards,
Massimo.